# Installing and configuring SQL Server 2008 R2 Full-Text Search through Linux (Ubuntu 16)

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, full-text-search, ubuntu-16.04

I am wondering if there is a way I can install and configure SQL Server 2008 R2 Full-Text Search through Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). Possibly using the sqlcmd cli interface for SQL Server vNext could work? Haven't been able to find info to manage that. Seems like I need SSMS to do it which I don't think is compatible with Linux systems. Hopefully that isn't the case. My laptop is Linux only and might have some drastic performance issues if I try to install Windows 10 partition (Also I don't own this laptop, as it is a bit dated and I am already dealing with some concerning slowdown from time to time). I am hoping to avoid having to use a Windows OS to do this.

Comment: I think this link might be helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

To install sqlcmd on Ubuntu 16.04 do the following:

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-tools.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev-utf16
```

You should be able to run sqlcmd after this.

Comment: Has anyone actually done this and gotten this to work?

Comment: Already installed sqlcmd

I am wondering if there is a way to install and configure Full-Text Search with sqlcmd only.